# Apps script to append doc pages for mass direct mail

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

I've wrote a script in google sheets that generates a list of customers membership expiry dates that are due to expire in the next 30 days. this list is generated each week. The goal is to write to these customers (direct mail) telling them their membership is due to expire.

I want to create 1 document that contains say 20 letters / pages for each customer thats been flagged as due to expire. That way for automation I am able to just print 1 document instead of opening 20 individual docs and printing.

I know how to create 20 individual letters using a letter template. I don't know how to merge those 20 into 1 document. or even better instead of merging at time of creating just do a for each loop that adds the customers details into the template and adds a new page for the next customers details using the same template.

Any advise or solution would be most appreciated.

```
data.forEach(function (row) {

    const template = DriveApp.getFileById("1234");
    const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ABC")

    const copy = template.makeCopy("letter", destFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();

    body.replaceText('{(First Name)}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{(Last Name)}', row[1]);

    doc.saveAndClose();

    }

  });
```

Comment: What do you mean by direct mail?

Comment: Physical mail. I.e a postal letter

Comment: Okay.  So if you are going to customize every letter for each user how do you plan to avoid not printing out twenty different letters?

Comment: I want to print out 20 different letters. However if all 20 were in the same docs document that would be an ideal solution instead of 20 separate docs documents

Comment: I think you will find that google docs does not handle pagination very well.  The pages just run together.  So I would just create a separate document.  You put them all into a zip file if you wish.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may want to try [AutoCrat](https://cloudlab.newvisions.org/autocrat) instead of writing your own code. For other options, choose **Extensions > Add-ons > Get add-ons** and search for  `mail merge`. See [mail merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_merge).